# Parsing a binary file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binaryfiles

I need to be able to parse a binary file with Ruby. This file contains chunks of data that are found via a header that includes the file offset and length of each chunk.

How do I get the data out correctly? I've been unable so far to seek around in the file based on the offsets I read out since they come out in strings that I don't know how to convert to a format IO#seek understands.

Any help? A general way to convert the offset and length into something usable (like an integer or something) would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [String#unpack](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ref_c_string.html#String.unpack).

Comment: That was it. unpack('L*') is what I needed.

Comment: You should be explicitly using the little-endian or big-endian unpacks instead of native-endian, to keep a bit of portability.

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a look at [BitStruct](http://bit-struct.rubyforge.org/) which offers a nice high-level interface for parsing binary data.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the BinData gem, and the alternatives it lists:

http://bindata.rubyforge.org/#alternatives